# How to jump to module location by character position? Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, there is an error text in which the character position is indicated. How to go to this place in the module?

```
... in position 599
```

Comment: FYI: I have created an issue in Github repo of vscode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196067  ... let's see how it goes

Answer (score 9):

A simpler solution is just to select text and check how many characters are selected.

Comment: this answer is up there with that guy who first said "why dont we make this wheel thing round"

Comment: It might be a suitable solution if you have the line number and character index in that line, but when it's `599` like in OP's question then it becomes impractical.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't find any vscode documentation about this feature.
That said, I did find this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davidfreer.go-to-character-position) that completely solved my problem.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that crazy that you need an extension for that?? It should be a basic functionality. I just used this extension and the position he moved to was incorrect (not matching what I expected while Notepad++ does). Such a pity VS Code does not have this built-in

Comment: Hi @Jean-FrancoisT I'm the creator of that extension and I agree with you. It's very sad, and what's even more crazy, I created that extension 2 years ago, 6 years after vscode was a public distribution so that says a lot more in my opinion. There are also other limitations with the extension route, most notably the file size limit for extensions (which maxes at 50mb [ref](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146784#issuecomment-1089253422))

Comment: @soulshined  I salute your work on this extension... what's even more surprising is that I have not found any ticket about this feature need anywhwere... so I had to create one myself: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196067   (on the other hand, I have been using VS Code since almost the beginning and never had this need before ... or more probably I was just using Notepad++ when I had to go there)

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Yes. That’s another problem they have in the eco system. If you look at feature requests you’ll see a common theme of responses like “this is a good candidate for an extension” which is why I didn’t bother at the time. I don’t believe this specific ask should go through the voting phase because it’s a core function of text editing software. There are many reasons why this shouldn’t be an extension. The issue you raised on my GitHub for one & other things like what does ‘position’ mean for localization, multi-byte chars etc. I’ll see if I can add a write up to your request

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. I am using the Go To position extension. Adding a feature to go to position on a specific/selected line would be good.

Comment: @Venkat: You can with the "Go To" feature of VS Code: just enter `:<line nb>:<char nb>` (e.g. `:214:36` to go to character 36 of line 214).

Answer (score 3):

I have created a ticket for this very feature to be added in VS Code: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196067

This is the current response from Microsoft (20th Oct 2023):

> This feature request is now a candidate for our backlog. The community has 60 days to upvote the issue. If it receives 20 upvotes we will move it to our backlog. If not, we will close it. To learn more about how we handle feature requests, please see our documentation.
>
> Happy Coding!

**If you need this feature, I encourage everyone of you to upvote the ticket by putting a thumbup  in the first message.**

Thanks